# Is it possible to save data in both vinyl and memtx at the same time?

Tags: tarantool

In my project I want to store some data in fast storage, but some data is too large to be stored in RAM. Can I store some data in memtx and some in vinyl?

Answer (score 1):

Tarantool works just fine with `memtx` and `vinyl` spaces under one process. So you just create a space, specify engine type (`memtx|vinyl`) and you are good to go. See [documentation](https://www.tarantool.io/en/doc/2.3/reference/reference_lua/box_schema/#box-schema-space-create) for more info.

```
box.cfg{}
box.schema.create_space('memtx_test', {engine = 'memtx'})
box.schema.create_space('vinyl_test', {engine = 'vinyl'})
```

However, there may be complex scenarios. For example, you may want to expire your `memtx` (hot/fast) data into `vinyl` (cold/slow) storage and you want to do it atomically. Tarantool doesn't yet support [cross-engine transactions](https://github.com/tarantool/tarantool/issues/1803) so you won't be able to delete a tuple from `memtx` space and insert it into `vinyl` space in one transaction. For such use case you may need to build some workaround like maintaining a third space (`memtx`) for temporary data.